# Call function of angularjs instead of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

AngularJS has functions which override jquery functions. For e.g., `wrap()` function is there in `angular.js` and in `jquery-1.10.2` also but I want to call the `wrap()` function of `angular.js` so how should I call it?

For now, when I try to call it in my directive like this, it calls the jquery's wrap() function:

```
element.wrap(outerDiv);
```

The need of this is, wrap() function doesn't work properly if it's called from jquery. Though it wraps the elements, it doesn't give angular environment, e.g. `{{ name }}` does not print `name` property. When I removed jquery file, `wrap()` function of `angular.js` was called and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Shouldn't the function do the same thing since angular is using a jquery light version

Comment: @Hatsjoem: Well, I also first thought that it might be some issue with `wrap()` function but then came to know that if I remove jquery or if somehow the function from angular.js is called instead of jquery, it works well and provides angular environment.

Comment: You always use the wrap of jquery when jquery is included. That's the idea behind that. It rly should do the same!

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for it?

Answer (score 2):

The angular js function `.wrap()` is the same as the jQuery function `.wrap()`.

Quoted from the docs:

> If jQuery is available, `angular.element` is an alias for the jQuery
>   function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to
>   Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."
>   [source](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

So meaning if you have jQuery included, the angular js function `wrap()` will be an alias for the jQuery function wrap else it will be jqLites `.wrap()` (which is the same).

Comment: I also thought so but seems this is a bug. Because once I remove jquery, it works fine. But when jquery is present, it doesn't print the model values in the `div` tag which is a wrapping element. Try it, wrap an input element with some div and print the model value in div, it would print `{{ name }}` only instead of the actual value of name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid reading up too much you could use the jquery functions which take the element as parameter instead of the methods prototyped onto the jQuery object.

Then again one might look at this as a workaround.